# Why is my PHP function not producing any output?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, echo

The following code shows a multi-dimensional array, and a function that loops through the array to echo out a nested menu with links.

However, the function doesn't appear to be working as nothing is being echoed.

It was working but I have changed a few includes around, so could it be something to do with that?

```
<?php

$urls = array (
    0=>array (
        0=>"Home",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/",
        2=>"Home",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    1=>array (
        0=>"Blog",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/blog/",
        2=>"Blog",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    2=>array (
        0=>"Glossary",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/",
        2=>"Glossary",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    3=>array (
        0=>"Resources",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/blog/",
        2=>"Resources",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    4=>array (
        0=>"Staff",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/",
        2=>"Staff",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    5=>array (
        0=>"Blog",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/blog/",
        2=>"Blog",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    6=>array (
        0=>"Home",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/",
        2=>"Home",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    ),

    7=>array (
        0=>"Blog",
        1=>"http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/blog/",
        2=>"Blog",
        3=>"",
        4=>"",
        5=>"1"
    )       
);

function showMenu()
{
    $top = count($urls);
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$top;$i++) {
        echo "<li><a href='".$urls[$i][1]."' title='".$urls[$i][2]."'>".$urls[$i][0]."</a><li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>

<?php showMenu(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it not outputting correctly? My crystal ball is being repaired currently. I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code.

Comment: Wow.... shouldn't that be filtered? Only code, no text.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  What is happening now?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` => *Notice: Undefined variable: urls in x.php on line 81*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the `$urls` variable from inside the function, which is not possible. You must pass the array into the function or letting the function know that is a global variable. Here's a modified version of your code that will work:

```
function showMenu($urls)
{
    $top = count($urls);
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$top;$i++) {
        echo "<li><a href='".$urls[$i][1]."' title='".$urls[$i][2]."'>".$urls[$i][0]."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>

<?php showMenu($urls); ?>
```

I also fixed the missing `/`in the closing `<li>`

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't even noticed the missing /.

Answer (score 7):

After taking a step back, I noticed your problem. Replace `showMenu` with this:

```
function showMenu()
{
    global $urls;
    $top = count($urls);
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$top;$i++) {
        echo "<li><a href='".$urls[$i][1]."' title='".$urls[$i][2]."'>".$urls[$i][0]."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

You had declared `$urls` outside the scope of the function. In the future, please tell us what's wrong with your code in the question, instead of making us guess.

Comment: Thank you. That has sorted it, can you please explain why this has fixed it?

Comment: @Mike: `global $urls;` will redeclare `$urls` in the local scope of the function, based on the existing global one.

Comment: Oh and fix your `<li>` to a `</li>` at the end of the echo line as well, credit to @KurtFunai for that one.

Comment: @djaqeel: Read my comment directly above yours. I'll edit the answer though to include this change. And he is calling `showMenu` in his code already, so I will not include that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

URLS is defined outside the scope of the function showMenu, so it doesn't know that function exists. You can use the global method to bring it in:

```
function showMenu() {
  global $urls;
  [...]
}
```

Or you can pass it as a variable:

```
$urls = array();

function showMenu($urls) {
  [...]
}

showMenu($urls);
```

Or you could just define $urls within the function itself.

Also, you might be interested to know that you don't have to explicitly number the array. You could more easily type it as:

```
$urls = array(
  array()
  ,array()
  ,array()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing the slash on your closing list element:

```
echo "<li><a href='".$urls[$i][1]."' title='".$urls[$i][2]."'>".$urls[$i][0]."</a><li>";
```

**Should be:**

```
echo "<li><a href='".$urls[$i][1]."' title='".$urls[$i][2]."'>".$urls[$i][0]."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your array outside your function, so it will not have any scope within your function. Either declare the array as a global, or pass the array to the function. I would prefer the latter.

Comment: Why would you prefer the latter? Are there performance gains? Or is it just a personal thing, is there any benefit to parsing it to the function?

Comment: "Global variables in software are generally a bad idea. They serve to magically teleport information from one place in a program to another in a way that is very hard to follow. Thus they cause subtle bugs, make maintenance difficult, and kill kittens." -http://tjhunt.blogspot.com/2009/04/php-global-variables-are-not.html

Comment: Use them when they're needed and called for, but not just because it will help you do what you're trying to do when there is a more..accepted/standard way to do it. Coding your php functions like this will get you into a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put

```
global $urls;
```

at the top of your showMenu function.

```
function showMenu()
{ 
    global $urls;
    $top = count($urls);
    ...
```